# Installing Tracks 2.2.3 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, debian, web-server, ruby, timekeeping

I want to install [Tracks](http://www.getontracks.org) on my Raspberry Pi for task/time management. My Pi is running the latest [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org), i.e. I have updated it to the latest package versions.

There is a rather cryptic guide on installing it [here](http://www.pihomeserver.fr/en/2013/08/22/raspberry-pi-home-server-gerer-vos-taches-avec-tracks). Unfortunately, I couldn't follow these instructions due to errors, I suspect that this is because of software versions being too new.

I tried the following approach:

- using `ruby1.8` / `ruby1.8-dev`, because those versions are closer to the versions from the guide. At `bundle install --without development,test` the process failed at a package telling me that `ruby1.9.2` was needed (I don't have the extact message anymore, but if needed I could do it again).
- I reverted the system back to before the first attempt and installed `ruby1.9.1` / `ruby1.9.1-dev`. Again a failure occurs, with this message:

  ```
  Installing htmlentities 4.3.1
  Installing jquery-rails 2.3.0
  Installing libv8 3.16.14.3
  Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
          /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
  checking for ruby/thread.h... no
  checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
  checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
  checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
  checking for rb_intern3()... yes
  checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
  checking for main() in -lm... yes
  checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
  checking for main() in -lz... yes
  checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
  checking for main() in -lsocket... no
  checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
  checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
  checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
  checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
  checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
  *** extconf.rb failed ***
  Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
  necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
  details.  You may need configuration options.

  Provided configuration options:
          --with-opt-dir
          --without-opt-dir
          --with-opt-include
          --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
          --with-opt-lib
          --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
          --with-make-prog
          --without-make-prog
          --srcdir=.
          --curdir
          --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
          --with-mysql-dir
          --without-mysql-dir
          --with-mysql-include
          --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
          --with-mysql-lib
          --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
          --with-mysql-config
          --without-mysql-config
          --with-mysql-dir
          --without-mysql-dir
          --with-mysql-include
          --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
          --with-mysql-lib
          --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
          --with-mysqlclientlib
          --without-mysqlclientlib
          --with-mlib
          --without-mlib
          --with-mysqlclientlib
          --without-mysqlclientlib
          --with-zlib
          --without-zlib
          --with-mysqlclientlib
          --without-mysqlclientlib
          --with-socketlib
          --without-socketlib
          --with-mysqlclientlib
          --without-mysqlclientlib
          --with-nsllib
          --without-nsllib
          --with-mysqlclientlib
          --without-mysqlclientlib
          --with-mygcclib
          --without-mygcclib
          --with-mysqlclientlib
          --without-mysqlclientlib


  Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.16 for inspection.
  Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
  An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
  Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'` succeeds before bundling.
  ```

Since I have never used Ruby I have no idea how to continue. So my questions:

1. what can I do to continue with the installation?
2. is there another guide on installing Tracks? The commands are totally messed up!
3. is there an alternative to Tracks that works on the RP and is equally good?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you don't have all the prerequisites installed (specifically MySQL). Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

I did this successfully, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tracksapp/n3Mryd-O7HY for step by step instructions.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please try to explain what to do to solve the issue. Link-only answers are a little undesired.